# Foursquare connected app- in app venue as detail url?

Tags: foursquare

I'm building a foursquare connected app and I want to suggest an alternative venue to a user after he/she checks in.

I'm using the explore endpoint to suggest an alternative venue, but I want the url in my checkin reply to lead the user to that venue page inside the foursquare application.

The [docs state that you can use a number of protocols](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/reply), http://, sms://, foursquare://, etc.

[Elsewhere in the docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#appintegration), foursquare provides uri's for accessing specific views inside the application, but notes that if your client is platform agnostic to use the Android intent addresses, as they fallback nicely to the mobile web page on other platforms (iOS, WP, etc).

The problem I've run into with the Android intents is that when clicking through to the detail url, the user hits the foursquare mobile web login screen, which is pretty poor user experience.

Seeing as my foursquare connected app is a web app and not native, I can't pass the iPhone URL as it presumably won't do anything on non-iOS devices. I also have no way of knowing what device my user is on (the POST request comes from foursquare so there's no user agent string to help me).

Is there a way to have the checkin reply url direct the user to a venue page (for a venue id) inside the foursquare application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you're displaying content to a user within the foursquare app, it's totally reasonable to use the foursquare:// domains (since there's no need for a "no foursquare app installed" fallback). The published custom domain URLs work in android, iOS, and blackberry.

To link to a venue screen within foursquare, use foursquare://venues/VENUE_ID

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a 400 `url param is invalid or unsupported` when sending a POST request to `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/506b3970e4b0831afe38aa49/reply?text=redacted&url=foursquare://venues/4acf7cadf964a52003d420e3&oauth_token=[redacted]`

Comment: After recognizing this as a bug, the foursquare team was quick to fix. Thanks Akshay & team!